# In Android studio unable import the kotlin. Could not download kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

When i'm creating the kotlin project build is failing due to

```
 What went wrong:
```

A problem occurred configuring root project 'SampleFirstApp'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.3.7/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.7.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/ad426ec76f52b1dcdf200f55495aea9a2d2796811884e8c4b514645061cf59f3?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.7.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYWQ0MjZlYzc2ZjUyYjFkY2RmMjAwZjU1NDk1YWVhOWEyZDI3OTY4MTE4ODRlOGM0YjUxNDY0NTA2MWNmNTlmMz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmtvdGxpbngtY29yb3V0aW5lcy1jb3JlLTEuMy43LmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwMDA3NzM5N30sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=QWeAM~fwvUMegI6EgefXgSAV0Cd6m~ULFAMUE2DboAuh1jEkoNp2tE-vpfsgBiehCl5ECs1t96jQrP26I3gGCfeWG-rX1qWAmrMfxESzhPjlvQWs5jOLLuFt8tlnuw6YJeUAbMRlV5mgUXv4~NhqxZ3qhT9XsN3XlTHJXIEKNkyjymJfdWgk2RRFyNFs3aRNIBwPJoNIRx6QiLeYf2MmL43jTxvS~moILHqWwtIoS5G6ObVtLVmOvaCN0QxApaBtcSytM3PKAfaGhnSJoCUCu4G~8d03tMfXdqnH6BsQ7Th1BLTOSQQaI3y8Z2s9xpv9ZsRmm3bJ0lC5oC~63lpjSg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.

this error is coming

My kotlin version in studio is 1.4.10. I have tried all solutions available in google and SO. I have invalidate and cache studio  and clean and rebuild the application.

My gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.e.samplefirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file

Comment: @peshkira i have added the gradle file please check once. It is new project nothing added my android studio version is 4.0